Annhilator generated by linear functional
I have to prove that, when $V$ is a vector space with dim$V$ = n and $f \in V^*$, there exist a subspace $ W$ with dim$W$ = n-1 such that $W^0$ = span{$f$}.
Now, initially I tried to do this : We now that a linear functional determines an hyperspace : Ker($f$) has dimension n-1.
So let $W$ = {$v \in V : f(v)=0$} = ker($f$)
Now I think this approach has a problem. If we take $W^0$ ={$h \in V^* : h(w) = 0 \space \space \forall w\in W$}, then we cannot guarantee that $W^0  \subseteq$ span{$f$}, and the reason is that $W^0$ contains all $h$ such that $h(w)=0$, and $h$ does not need to be a linear combination of $f$.
I am correct? If I am, how can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Your found the right subpace $W$. What remains to do is to prove that if $h\in V^*$ satisfies $h(w)=0$ for all $w\in \ker(f)$, then $h=\mu f$ for some $\mu\in K$, where $K$ is your favourite base field.
Note that you want $f$ to be non identically zero, otherwise the result you try to prove is false. Note also that if $h\neq 0$, the result is clear.
So assume that $h\neq 0$ too.
Here is a list of hints.

Prove that there is $x_0\in V$ such that $f(x_0)=1$.

Prove that $V=\ker(f)\oplus K x_0$.

Assuming that $h$ is zero on $\ker(f)$, compare $h(w+\lambda x_0)$ and $f(w+\lambda x_0)$ for all $\lambda\in K$ and $w\in \ker(f)$, and conclude.


